# Unable to launch Jupyter notebook in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda, and when I try to launch jupyter notebook, it gives me this error.
Also, when I first started Anaconda, it gave me this message : "environment is no longer available "
I'm not sure if that's connected, or not.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 59, in 
from tornado import httpserver
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in 
from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in 
from tornado import iostream
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in 
from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 35, in 
_client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\ssl.py", line 775, in create_default_context
context.load_default_certs(purpose)
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\ssl.py", line 596, in load_default_certs
self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
File "C:\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\Python\Lib\ssl.py", line 588, in _load_windows_store_certs
self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: [ASN1] nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4004)
```

I've reinstalled the app multiple times, nothing happened. Also, tried doing this

```bash
conda uninstall pyzmq  # (This also removes jupyter related packages!)
conda install pyzmq  # (to reinstall it)
conda install jupyter  # (to reinstall jupyter related packages)
```

and it's not working.

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303580/error-launching-jupyter-notebook-ssl-sslerror-asn1-nested-asn1-error

Comment: Guess that will solve the problem. It works :) Thanks